# Philips Hue API is unable to detect lights and scenes

Tags: philips-hue

I have an issue discovering my lights using the Philips Hue API.

(The bridge and the devices run on the latest version)

The connection and connection to the bridge work without issues. When I try to access my lamps using /api/userid/lights (or just in the bridge - /api/userid), I just get an empty list. The same thing applies for my scenes.

[image: Insomnia shows empty list]

I can see the lamps and scenes within the HUE App though.

If I try to detect new devices via the API ([POST] /api/userid/lights) it is not able to find anything as well. I am trying to access two play light bars. They are connected via bluetooth to the bridge, but that should not be an issue, right?

I also can't find them using the following endpoint: /clip/v2/resource/device